# Grouping Product or Creating into a set

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, bundled-product, grouped-products

I'm a newbie around here!

Is there any way for me create a combination of 2-3 products and creates a set?

say. Sofa Module A, B, C all selling separately and have they're individual SKU's

I want to create SOFA combo A.

I tried group product, didn't seem to work? 
bundle or Configurable?

Answer (score 0):

You are near, [Grouped Product](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-grouped.html) is the one you should go for. According to official document:

> A grouped product is made up of simple standalone products that are presented as a group

If you found any difficulties on creating grouped product, you can refer to official document.